# How to make a javascript/mailchimp function to submit form data on click

Tags: javascript, html, forms, mailchimp

I have a contact form using Mailchimp and it works, however I need a new function because I have another form on my website but I can't use the contact one because it doesn't have the same fields as the other one. And sinceI'm kinda new to javascript, I don't know how to make one. Can you help me?

I have tried recreating the same function of the contact form but with the new fields, but it doesn't submit the form. This is what I've tried:

**JAVASCRIPT/MAILCHIMP FUNCTION**

```
$('#mc-embedded-download-form').ajaxChimp({
     callback: mailchimpCallback,
     url: "myURL"  
});

function mailchimpCallback2(resp2) {
    if (resp2.result === 'success') {
      $.growl({ title: "Thanks!", message: "Your message has been sent 
  sucessfully. <br/>We'll be in touch soon.", duration: 7000, style: 
  "notice" });
      $('#mcee-NAME').val('');
      $('#mcee-EMAIL').val('');
      $('#mcee-CHECK').val('');

    } else if(resp.result === 'error') {
     $.growl({ title: "Oops...", message: "An error has occurred sending your message.<br/>", duration: 7000, style: "error" });
     }  
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="subscribe-section">         
            <form class="subscription-form mailchimp form-inline" role="form" action="" method="post" id="mc-embedded-download-form" name="mc-embedded-download-form" >
            <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                <div class="mc-field-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Type your name here" value="" aria-required="true"
                                         name="NAME" class="form-control input-box required pull-right" id="mcee-NOME">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Type your email here" value="" aria-required="true"
                                         name="EMAIL" class="form-control input-box required pull-left" id="mcee-EMAIL">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="aceite" value="1" aria-invalid="false" id="mcee-CHECK">
                    <span> Autorizo o envio das informações preenchidas para a abase de dados do CYBER1 GROUP, para utiização no envio de mensagens específicas sobre os serviços da Cyber1 e demais temas relacionados com nossa empresa.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div id="mce-responses" class="container">
                    <div class="subscription-error" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                    <div class="subscription-success" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_d8293ae5cf8e0541d08b72ed3_d5c30164bd" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <input type="submit" value="Fazer download do E-BOOK!" name="download" id="mc-embedded-download" class="btn standard-button lang" key="sec0-botao">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Form action=" url " have you assign

Comment: @Husna can you elaborate please?

Comment: action="http://xxxxx.us#.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post-json?u=xxxxx&id=xxxx&c=?"